# Function exceptions specification and standard exceptions - foo() throw(Exception)

Tags: c++, exception, throw

In C++ you may declare function with exception specification like this:

```
int foo() const throw(Exception);
```

I found those two links:

- http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/exceptions/ and
- http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/lnxpcomp/v8v101/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.xlcpp8l.doc%2Flanguage%2Fref%2Fcplr156.htm

But several things end up unanswered...

**Question 1:** why to add exception specification? Will it bring any performance increase? What will be different for compiler? Because it seems just like an information for programmer to me.

**Question 2:** what will happend (what should happen) if I throw something that isn't in specification? For example:

```
int foo() throw(int) {
        throw char; // Totally unrelated classes, not types in real
}
```

**Question 3:** function/method shouldn't throw anything. I found at least two (three, alternative syntax for different compilers) ways to specify no exception throwing:

- `int foo() throw();`
- `int foo() __attribute(nothrow)__` for gcc
- `int foo() nothrow` for visual C++

Which one is "correct"? Is there any difference? Which one should I use?

**Question 4:** "standart exceptions", `bad_alloc`,`bad_cast`,`bad_exception`,`bad_typeid` and `ios_base::failure`.

Ok `bad_alloc` is self explaining and I know how (and more importantly when) to use it (add to exception specification), but what about the others? None of them does really ring a bell... Which "code pieces" are they associated with? Like `bad_alloc` is associated with `new char[500000]`.

**Question 5:** If I have exception classes hierarchy, like this:

```
    class ExceptionFileType {
             virtual const char * getError() const = 0;
    };

    class ExceptionFileTypeMissing : public ExceptionFileType {
            virtual const char *getError() cosnt {
                    return "Missing file";
            }
    }
```

Should I use:

```
    int foo() throw(ExceptionFileType);
```

Or:

```
    int foo() throw(ExceptionFileTypeMissing,ExceptionFileTypeNotWritable,ExceptionFileTypeNotReadable,...)
```

<sub>Note: answers with references would be great. I'm looking for good practice tips.</sub>

Comment: See [Should I use an exception specifier in C++?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/88573/should-i-use-an-exception-specifier-in-c).

Comment: Don't use exception specifications, they're useless and deprecated in C++11. The only useful part of that is `throw()`, which has been superseded by `noexcept` in 11.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The simple "good practice" tip is: don't use exception specifications.

Essentially the only exception to that is the possibility of an empty exception specification: `throw()`. That's sufficiently useful that in C++11 it's been given its own keyword (`noexcept`). It's generally agreed that any non-empty exception specification is a lousy idea though.

Exception specifications (other than `noexcept`) are officially deprecated -- and unlike many deprecated features, removing this would affect little enough source code that I think there's a good chance it really will eventually be removed (certainly no guarantee, but a pretty fair chance anyway).

As for what happens when/if you do throw an exception of a type not allowed by the exception specification: `std::unexpected()` gets invoked. By default, that invokes `terminate()`. You can use `std::set_unexpected` to set your own handler -- but about all you can reasonably do is add some logging before you `terminate()`. Your unexpected handler is not allowed to return.

Comment: I'm not sure about the "never been used much".  The functions in `std::exception` had them, which meant that anyone deriving their own exception classes had to use them.  (Admittedly `throw()`.)

Comment: @JamesKanze: Thanks -- I've rephrased it to be more accurate.

Comment: Can you provide some reference for "It's generally agreed that any non-empty exception specification is a lousy idea though."? My project leader won't accept "answer on stackoverflow" as reliable source (although your reputation is pretty impressive) :-/

Comment: @Vyktor: Because it's cumbersome to write and doesn't really protect you from anything.

Comment: One possibility would be [Guru of the Week #82](http://www.gotw.ca/gotw/082.htm) (Herb Sutter).

Comment: @CatPlusPlus I like this answer very much, but if Jerry could provide some article or link or something what I could show to my teamleader and add into documentation I'll be glad to have it consistent and "official".

Comment: @Vyktor: I'm not sure if you've seen the mention of GotW above, but if not, it's a worthwhile read (not just as backing for this answer). Boost's standards also advise: "Avoid exception-specifications.", giving the following rationale. I'd also think that §D.4 of the new standard: "The use of dynamic-exception-specifications is deprecated." might qualify as the best support of all (about as official as you can get, anyway).

Comment: @JerryCoffin thank you for your effort I'm already reading provided link (GotW) it'll be used for good :P

Comment: @Vyktor: The definitive reference for C++03 is _C++ Coding Standards_, Item 75. "Avoid exception specifications."

Comment: "Your unexpected handler is not allowed to return." - true, but it *is* allowed to throw an exception, and the program can continue if that is handled. Termination is not inevitable.

Answer (score 3):

**Question 1**

Don't bother. They were a bad idea, and were deprecated in the latest version of the language. They give no benefit to the compiler, since they are checked at runtime; if anything, they might hurt performance in some cases.

**Question 2**

A function called `std::unexpected` will be called. By default, this calls `std::terminate`; by default, that terminates the program. Both of these behaviours can be changed, using `std::set_unexpected` and `std::set_terminate` to install your own handler, if you really want to.

**Question 3**

`throw()` was the standard way to do it; the others are non-portable compiler extensions. In C++11, you might use `noexcept`, which gives a compile-time check that nothing can throw, rather than a run-time check that nothing does throw.

**Question 4**

- `bad_cast` is thrown when a `dynamic_cast` of a reference fails.
- `bad_exception` is thrown in some weird circumstances when an exception specification is violated.
- `bad_typeid` is thrown if evaluating the argument to `typeid` involves dereferencing a null pointer
- `ios_base::failure` is thrown by the input/output library (`<iostream>` etc.) when some operations fail

**Question 5**

If you want to allow the entire heirarchy to be thrown, then just specify the base class. But you shouldn't be using exception specifiers at all.

Answer (score 2):

First, let's be very clear what an exception specification does: it's
more or less like an `assert` that can't be disabled, asserting that you
will not exit the function with an exception **other** than the ones
missing.  As such, it's utility is far more limited than it would seem
at first; for the most part (and in this case, I can't imagine an 
exception), the only really useful guarantee is `throw()`, which
guarantees that no exception will be thrown; if you want to write
exception safe code, you'll need this guarantee for a few low level
functions.

In practice, although `throw()` could allow some additional compiler
optimizations, the generic implementation tends to result in less 
efficient code when an exception specification is used.  In C++11, the
`throw()` has been replaced by `noexcept`, presumably with the hope that
compiler implementers will do something intelligent with it.

EDIT:

Since everyone (including myself) seems to have missed your question 4:

`bad_alloc` will be thrown by the `operator new` function if it cannot
allocate the memory.

`bad_cast` will be thrown by a `dynamic_cast` to a reference, in the
case where the cast fails.  (A `dynamic_cast` to a pointer returns a
null pointer in such cases.)

`bad_exception` will be thrown when an exception specification is
violated, provided the exception specification allows `bad_exception`.
(In other words, forget it.)

`bad_typeid` will be thrown if you try to use `typeid` with a null
pointer.

`ios_base::failure` will be thrown if you request a stream to throw in
case of errors.

Practically speaking: you'll catch `bad_alloc` if you want to recover
and continue from out of memory situations.  Which means not very often.
(It's very, very difficult to recover from an out of memory situation.)
For `bad_cast`, it's probably preferrable to use pointers, and test for
null, if you aren't sure.  And there's no excuse for ever seeing a
`bad_typeid`.  Most of the time, you'll probably want to test IO errors
explicitly, rather than configuring the stream to throw exceptions; and
exception when `ios_base::badbit` is set might be an exception (since it
represents a truly exceptional case of a hardward fault).

Answer (score 1):

Questions 1 and 2 are addressed at some length in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2501745/212858).

Questions 3 and 5 are covered by the recommendation, in the accepted answer to that question, that you don't use exception specifications at all.

Question 4 seems to be adequately addressed by typing those exception names into the search engine of your choice, or consulting the index of a good C++ book.  Do you have a specific query about them?