# does throw in a C++ function declaration preclude throwing other exceptions?

Tags: c++, exception

I inherited a C++ project with a function defined like so:

`void myDoc::parseDoc(string& path) throw(docError);`

The `parseDoc` function calls a library that throws `libError`, and the main function that calls `parseDoc` catches both `docError` and `libError` and logs them.  `parseDoc` doesn't throw any exceptions itself, but I would've expected the `libError`s from the library to still get caught by `main`.  They don't - I just get a core dump with nothing useful on the stack.

I tried various changes to `parseDoc`. Some of them get `libError` passed up the chain. and some don't:

1. catch `libError` and rethrow it - doesn't work
2. catch `libError` and copy it to a `docError` and throw that - works
3. specify `throw(docError, libError)` and not catch anything - works
4. remove the `throw()` from the function definition and not catch anything - works

So my question is - does adding a `throw(docError)` to this function definition specifically prevent other exceptions from being passed up the stack to the caller?  If so, why would anyone want to do that?  And if *not* specifying that a function throws exceptions just works the way I always thought exceptions were supposed to work, what's the point of the `throw(e)` specification in the first place?

Comment: you may be interested in [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9418180/function-exceptions-specification-and-standart-exceptions-foo-throwexceptio?rq=1) question.

Comment: I would say, *"start* by adding a "catch-all `try` statement" to the outer-level routine that will prevent the possibility of a core-dump. ### Then, "don't rely on being able to 're-throw' the exception that you presently have in your hand." Having caught a particular exception, and having decided that for whatever reason you can't handle it, throw a *new* one.

Comment: Actually, I just found http://www.gotw.ca/publications/mill22.htm, which explains this.  I didn't realize that the throw specification is explicitly for the purpose of preventing throwing of other exception types.  For hateful C++ theoretical reasons I don't begin to understand, but that the original coder thought he did... ;-)

Comment: Do #4. Throw specifications are actually deprecated anyway.

Answer (score 5):

Yes, a throw specification does not allow any exceptions except the specified to escape the function.

As for why anyone would want that, the idea is documentation, showing exactly which exceptions the function will throw.

However, in reality, the concept proved to be so useless that throw specifications were (or will be, not sure about the exact status) actually removed in a newer version of C++. So the correct action to take is number 4, removing the specification.

Comment: Are you sure that it was removed? As far as I know, it was only deprecated, cppreference.com says nothing about removal of this feature.

Comment: There's a proposal here: http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2016/p0003r2.html Not sure about its final status. Might be in C++17.

Comment: If they're taking suggestions, I'd suggest that when no catcher for an exception is found up the stack, and the default behavior is to core dump, please core dump without unwinding the stack first.  Why on earth would it make sense, if you're going to core dump, to discard all of the local context for the dump - rendering it essentially useless.  I guess that's implementation specific, but still...

Comment: But the behavior isn't to core dump, it's to call the unexpected handler, which can be dynamically changed at runtime with `std::set_unexpected`.